# Mathematical Induction and Divisibility $7\mid 11^n-4^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

Prove $11^{n} - 4^{n}$ is divisible by 7 for all natural numbers n.

I know this holds for the base case of n = 1. Am I supposed to use $11^{n + 1} - 4^{n + 1}$ for the induction step?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It might help you if you look at some similar problem from the past, for example, [Prove $7$ divides $13^n- 6^n$ for any positive integer](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1181297) or [Proof by induction: Show that $9^n-2^n$ for any $n$ natural number is divisible by $7$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1684456) More generally, many of questions tagged [divisibility+induction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisibility+induction) might be problems of this type.

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Thank you Martin! I will be sure to make my titles more informative!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have that $11\equiv 4 \pmod{7}.$ Thus 
$11^n\equiv 4^n \pmod{7}, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$ That is, $11^n-4^n$ is divisible by $7.$

If you want to use induction note that

$$11^{n+1}-4^{n+1}=(7+4)\cdot11^n-4\cdot4^n=7\cdot 11^n+4\cdot(11^n-4^n).$$ Now $7\cdot 11^n$ and $11^n-4^n$ are multiples of $7$ (the second one using the induction hypothesis).

Comment: The first proof using modular arithmetic also uses induction, e.g. in the proof of the [Congruence Power Rule.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)  The second proof is exactly the same proof, but with the modular arithmetic eliminated, as I explain at length in [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1179145/242)

Answer (score 6):

Without induction: $11^n-4^n=(11-4)(11^{n-1}+11^{n-2}\cdot 4 + \cdots + 4^{n-1})$ where $11-4=7$.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of induction, write $11^n$ as $(7+4)^n$ and expand using the binomial theorem. After you subtract away the $4^n$ term, every remaining term has at least one factor of $7$.

Answer (score 3):

If you have proved the base case, now move on to the induction step.

Assume $n=k$, and that $7|(11^k - 4^k)$. This means that $11^k - 4^k = 7M$

Now prove your induction step.

So that: $7|(11^k - 4^k) \to 7|(11^{k+1} - 4^{k+1})$

Answer (score 2):

**First, show that this is true for $n=1$:**

$11^{1}-4^{1}=7$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$11^{n}-4^{n}=7k$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$11^{n+1}-4^{n+1}=$

$11(11^{n})-\color\green{4}(4^{n})=$

$11(11^{n})-(\color\green{11-7})(4^{n})=$

$11(11^{n})-11(4^{n})+7(4^{n})=$

$11(\color\red{11^{n}-4^{n}})+7(4^{n})=$

$11(\color\red{7k})+7(4^{n})=$

$7(11k)+7(4^{n})=$

$7(11k+4^{n})$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

Comment: @Joffan: Thank you for the edit. For my "induction" answers, I have my own regular template which I prefer to keep :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to to do it without induction is to note that the mod cycles for powers of $11$ and $4$ modulo congruent to $7$ correspond to each other. 
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}11 &\equiv 4 \pmod 7\\ 11^2 &\equiv 2 \pmod 7\\ 11^3 &\equiv 1 \pmod 7 \\ 11^4 &\equiv 4 \pmod 7 \\ &\vdots\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}4 &\equiv 4 \pmod 7\\ 4^2 &\equiv 2 \pmod 7\\ 4^3 &\equiv 1 \pmod 7 \\ 4^4 &\equiv 4 \pmod 7 \\ &\vdots\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

So for any $n$, $11^n \equiv 4^n \equiv r \pmod 7$, so $11^n - 4^n \equiv r - r \pmod 7 \implies 11^n - 4^n \equiv 0 \pmod 7$ as desired.